# Error when running a huggingface model in 4bit mode in Streamlit using bitsnbytes. Quant state is being set to None unwillingly

Tags: streamlit, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, quantization

I am loading a huggingface starchat beta model in streamlit and caching it thus :

```py
@st.cache_resource
def load_model():
    """Initialize the tokenizer and the AI model."""

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta")
    print("loaded tokenizer")
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta",load_in_4bit=True, device_map="cuda")
    print("loaded models")
    return tokenizer,model
```

However while it loads the model with the same code when I am executing the code standalone, I am facing the following error in streamlit :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script    exec(code, module.__dict__)  File "/app.py", line 93, in <module>    main()  File "/app.py", line 73, in main    outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_new_tokens=256, do_sample=True, temperature=0.2, top_k=50, top_p=0.95, eos_token_id=49155)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context    return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1642, in generate    return self.sample(  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2724, in sample    outputs = self(  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt_bigcode/modeling_gpt_bigcode.py", line 808, in forward    transformer_outputs = self.transformer(  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt_bigcode/modeling_gpt_bigcode.py", line 673, in forward    outputs = block(  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt_bigcode/modeling_gpt_bigcode.py", line 316, in forward    attn_outputs = self.attn(  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt_bigcode/modeling_gpt_bigcode.py", line 230, in forward    query, key_value = self.c_attn(hidden_states).split((self.embed_dim, 2 * self.kv_dim), dim=2)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 248, in forward    out = bnb.matmul_4bit(x, self.weight.t(), bias=bias, quant_state=self.weight.quant_state)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py", line 567, in matmul_4bit    assert quant_state is not NoneAssertionError
```

I tried looking up for solutions but it seems none exist. The problem arises from line 567 in https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py, retracing my error steps points it to as originating from `model.generate(inputs, max_new_tokens=256, do_sample=True, temperature=0.2, top_k=50, top_p=0.95, eos_token_id=49155)` which works perfectly well if executing in a jupyter notebook shell instead of streamlit

Answer (score 0):

Change the device_map parameter to "auto".

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta",load_in_4bit=True, device_map="auto")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).